# Inheriting from a class with the same name from outside the namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application where there are multiple ways to handle creating and updating an object based on the user that is logged in. I keep getting a circular reference exception on the child classes. Is this correct or would it be better to create concerns module with shared code and have them both be independent?

```
class WorkOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
 #parent class
end

module Dispatch
  class WorkOrder < ::WorkOrder
    #child class
  end
end

module Service
  class WorkOrder < ::WorkOrder
    #child class
  end
end
```

Comment: Please show us the error message(s), as this code is valid in Ruby 2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

How are you planning on differentiating records in the database between being from the parent class or one of the child classes?

You may want to look at Single Table Inheritance (STI) and Polymorphic Associations:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations